# Attempting to mock a model facade returns an error that shouldReceive is not defined

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, laravel-4, mockery

(Using laravel "4.0.*", mockery "dev-master", and phpunit "3.7.*" from packagist)

I have been re factoring some code to make it more testable using the IoC container which, so far, has worked amazingly. I have found a controller which does the following

```
$batch = Batch::find($id)
```

Now I need to test this facade and I have found many resource that tell me I could just call shouldReceive on the model so I have the following in my unit test

```
Models\Batch::shouldReceive('find')
    ->once()
    ->with(10)
    ->andReturn($this->mock);
```

but that just triggers the following error

BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::shouldReceive()

I do not know what to do in this situation and I have not been able to find any resource online to help me out with this.

Answer (score 4):

`shouldReceive()` works for facades, but I don't think it works for models.

What you want to do here, I think, is just a regular Mockery mock injected into the app container.

[warning - untested code]

```
$mock = Mockery::mock('Batch');
$mock->shouldReceive('find')->once()->with(10)->andReturn($mock);
App::instance('Batch',$mock);

// rest of test follows.
```